# Can I have a single instance of SharePoint for several subdomains?

Tags: sharepoint, server, subdomain, windows-server-2012-r2, isolation

I'm doing some research for a SharePoint setup where a secure SharePoint is used by several customers while keeping the databases separated. The different customers shouldn't be able to connect to each others databases, but should use the same authentication method across all customers using this system. The plan is that this system will be used for production and use quite powerful servers. My question is, do I need to have more than one instance of SharePoint server to be able to handle different subdomains such as *https://customera.mysharepoint.com* and *https://customerb.mysharepoint.com*.

Worth mentioning I've been googling for about a day about this issue without finding what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,You can have single SharePoint server for many sub domains
SharePoint structure is hierarchical.

1. Farm
2. Web Applicatin
3. Site Collection
4. Sites

Each SharePoint farm can contain multiple web applications and each web application can bind to specific domain or subdomain.
Note that you can use only one instance of sharepoint on each server.

Comment: Only one instance of SharePoint on each server: So I can have one large SharePoint Farm with let's say 20 site collections where they all have separate content databases. And I can have a separate DB-server and Administrative server. But I guess the administrative server would need an own instance of SharePoint in that case?

Comment: SharePoint server installed on each server but only one instance is accessible , (concept of instance is software , but not web application pr server ) . As you know SharePoint farm contain multiple server. As your question and SharePoint hierarchically each web application can use specific domain (or even more) . host header site collection is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve what you're looking to do with SharePoint. I would recommend using host-header site collections to achieve what you want: each sub-domain will map to a SharePoint site collection.

This assumes you only need one site collection per sub-domain.

You could also have each sub-domain map to a SharePoint Web Application however you'll encounter a limit depending on how many sub-domains you need: a SharePoint farm can only support up to 20 SharePoint Web Applications.

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262787(v=office.16).aspx for the limits and boundaries in SharePoint 2016.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly: Word and other applications that we can find within Office365 or just to be able to be used in SharePoint can be applications. And then I can use several customers with different subdomains as sitecollections. Each sitecollection can then have a bunch of sites within itself?

Comment: I'll start bottom up. Yes, each site collection is made up of a series of sites within itself: there's usually a top-level or root site and zero or more children sites (each child site can also have it's own sub-sites so you have a hierarchy of sites within a site collection). You can have a sub-domain per customer and configure SharePoint to serve a site collection for each sub-domain (this is a host-header site collection). Some Office 365 applications are built on SharePoint (Videos, Delve) but Word is not one of them!